# Delete trigger not inserting record

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

Need a trigger which runs on deletion.
The code I wrote is not working: It is firing the trigger but is not inserting any records.

> I want it to insert the to be deleted row in a audit table.

My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [EXERCISE].[delete_trigger] ON [EXERCISE].[Fact_Sales]
AFTER DELETE
AS
       INSERT INTO [EXERCISE].[Fact_Sales_Audit](City_ID,Product_ID,Time_ID,Created_Date,Updated_Date)
       SELECT F.City_ID,F.Product_ID,F.Time_ID,F.Created_Date,F.Updated_Date
       FROM [EXERCISE].[Fact_Sales] F
       JOIN deleted D
       ON F.Fact_Sales_ID = D.Fact_Sales_ID
       PRINT 'Deleted row entered.'
```

It is not working. Reason I suspect is- the row is being deleted from the table before the trigger is fired and thats why it is not able to join and hence not  inserting any records. But when I debug and print messages I can see that trigger happens before deletion.

Can someone please explain me how exactly does this trigger work?

Comment: If you want to confrm you can convert the trigger to before dellete and execute, if the row is not getting inserted beacause the reason as you say it will be inserted then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting rows from the `[EXERCISE].[Fact_Sales]` table, yet in your trigger you are joining to this table, expecting the records to still be there - they are not.

At that point, the `Deleted` pseudo-table has the same schema as the `[EXERCISE].[Fact_Sales]` table, but with the rows you have just deleted in it. Instead of trying to join back to a table for rows you know aren't there any more, just use the `Deleted` table directly for your insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [EXERCISE].[delete_trigger]
ON [EXERCISE].[Fact_Sales]
AFTER DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO [EXERCISE].[Fact_Sales_Audit](City_ID,Product_ID,Time_ID,Created_Date,Updated_Date)
    SELECT D.City_ID,
           D.Product_ID,
           D.Time_ID,
           D.Created_Date,
           D.Updated_Date
    FROM   deleted D
```

The trigger does fire after the delete on the main table, as the `AFTER DELETE` syntax implies. It fires somewhere between when the delete statement is executed, and before the control is returned to the user. It takes place in the same transaction - e.g. if the delete was rolled back for whatever reason, the inserts performed by the trigger would also be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify your trigger definition to fetch just deleted row(s) from virtual table DELETED. What will happen is your deleted rows will be temporarily stored in that table and then will be inserted into audit table. 
*NB! Be sure you have set primary key on your Fact_Sales table.*

```
CREATE TRIGGER [delete_trigger] ON [Fact_Sales]
FOR DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO [Fact_Sales_Audit](Fact_Sales_Id,City_ID,Product_ID,Time_ID,Created_Date,Updated_Date)
    SELECT Fact_Sales_Id,City_ID,Product_ID,Time_ID,Created_Date,Updated_Date
    FROM DELETED
```